# Optimize rank computation for high dimension tensor

Tags: matrix, optimization, tensor, torch, rank

My programme wastes a lot of time on the code below, whereas it's been executed on the GPU machine. How can I optimise it please? The tensors can be of this size `y_ul.shape = [8, 512, 128, 128]`

```
for i, m in enumerate(y_ul):
    for j, l in enumerate(m):
        ranks_topleft.append(torch.matrix_rank(l))
mean_rank_topleft = torch.mean(ranks_topleft.float())
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike `torch.matrix_rank`, `torch.linalg.matrix_rank` allows batched inputs [documetation here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.linalg.matrix_rank.html). You can try:

```py
ranks = torch.linalg.matrix_rank(y_ul)  # shape (8, 512)
mean_rank_topleft = torch.mean(ranks)  # scalar
```

Note that you can adjust the tolerance for computation (but the one by default should be good). Plus if your matrices are symmetric, you can add `hermitian=True` to speed-up calculations.

Note that `torch.matrix_rank` is deprecated and will be removed in further versions!